# handling excpetions in plsql block while running in a loop

Tags: oracle, loops, exception, plsql

I have a requirement where I need to drop partitions for more than one tables in a loop.If for some reason that partition doesnt exist in a table the whole procedure is giving error . But I want to drop other partititions which exists in other tables without coming out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner begin-exception-end block ("inner" meaning "within a loop"). Something like this:

```
begin
  for cur_r in (select whatever from ...) loop

    -- inner block begins here
    begin
      do stuff here
    exception
      when ... then ...
    end;
    -- inner block ends here

  end loop;
end;
```